# Calling superclass constructor with super or just setTitle?

Tags: java, jframe

What is the recommended method of setting the title with `setTitle("Title")`or `super("Title")` while extending `javax.swing.JFrame` in terms of performance?

Comment: Don't extend `JFrame`, just use an instance.  But either way, you may as well pass the title in the constructor for the fact it is less code lines to create/configure an instance.  Also see [When to optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: *performance*? How many JFrames do you want to create? Millions a second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you grepcode `JFrame` (in OpenJDK 6-b14), and dig a bit, you see that the constructor `JFrame()` calls the constructor `Frame()`, which calls `Frame("")` ([link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Frame.java#Frame.%3Cinit%3E%28%29)).

So, since an implicit `super()` is added if you don't specify a call to any super constructor yourself, it would be (although very slightly so) more effective to call `super("Title")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in your constructor, try to delegate as much functionality as possible to the super constructor.  It's possible that you can save it from doing some work.

For instance, the default super constructor might create some inner objects that will just get overwritten when you call the setter.  If you pass the correct data immediately, you give it the opportunity to be more efficient.

But I think in this specific case, it does not matter much.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to always call the corresponding super(.....) when you extend a class.
As you never know what magic the super constructor does behind the scene.

You never need just

call super();

That's what will be there if you don't specify anything else. You only need to specify the constructor to call if:

- You want to call a superclass constructor which **has parameters**
- You want to chain to another constructor in the same class instead of the superclass constructor

Comment: Do you mean to explicitly call `super` when you extend a class? If so why? Because when you extend a class either explicitly or implicitly you do call `super`?